# How do I get corresponding values after groupby and aggr

Tags: python, python-polars

I am using polars with python and have this sample dataset:

```
dataset = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "Timestamps": ["2022-10-01 04:00:00", "2022-10-01 06:00:00", "2022-10-01 08:30:00", "2022-12-02 09:00:00", "2022-12-02 09:15:00", "2022-12-02 09:30:00", "2022-12-02 09:45:00", "2022-12-02 10:00:00", "2022-12-02 10:15:00"],
        "Date": ["2022-10-01", "2022-10-01", "2022-10-01", "2022-12-02", "2022-12-02", "2022-12-02", "2022-12-02", "2022-12-02", "2022-12-02"],
        "Values": [1, 2, 2, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 3],
    }
)
qa = dataset.lazy().with_columns(pl.col("Timestamps").str.strptime(pl.Datetime, "%Y-%m-%d %T"), pl.col("Date").str.strptime(pl.Date, "%Y-%m-%d"))
df1 = qa.collect()

┌─────────────────────┬────────────┬────────┐
│ Timestamps          ┆ Date       ┆ Values │
│ ---                 ┆ ---        ┆ ---    │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ date       ┆ i64    │
╞═════════════════════╪════════════╪════════╡
│ 2022-10-01 04:00:00 ┆ 2022-10-01 ┆ 1      │
│ 2022-10-01 06:00:00 ┆ 2022-10-01 ┆ 2      │
│ 2022-10-01 08:30:00 ┆ 2022-10-01 ┆ 2      │
│ 2022-12-02 09:00:00 ┆ 2022-12-02 ┆ 5      │
│ 2022-12-02 09:15:00 ┆ 2022-12-02 ┆ 4      │
└─────────────────────┴────────────┴────────┘
```

I would like to get the max and min value for every single Date together with the corresponding timestamp. The result for f.e the max value should look like this:

```
┌────────────┬────────┬─────────────────────┐
│ Date       ┆ Values ┆ Timestamps          │
│ ---        ┆ ---    ┆ ---                 │
│ date       ┆ i64    ┆ datetime[μs]        │
╞════════════╪════════╪═════════════════════╡
│ 2022-12-02 ┆ 5      ┆ 2022-12-02 09:00:00 │
│ 2022-10-01 ┆ 2      ┆ 2022-10-01 06:00:00 │
└────────────┴────────┴─────────────────────┘
```

Currently I've got this line but I can't figure out how to extract a value (timestamp) out of a column next to the aggregated value:

```
df1 = df1.groupby('Date').agg([pl.max('Values'), pl.max('Timestamps')]).sort("Date", descending=True)
```

Comment: Why isn't the max timestamp for `values=2` the `08:30:00`? Or on ties do you want all the timestamps?

Comment: The timestamp should ideally be the first (chronologically) that matches the value. In this case `2022-10-01 06:00:00`. So I'd need only one... the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say we start with...

```
dataset = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "Timestamps": ["2022-10-01 06:00:00", "2022-10-01 08:30:00", "2022-12-02 09:00:00", "2022-12-02 09:15:00", "2022-12-02 09:30:00", "2022-12-02 09:45:00", "2022-12-02 10:00:00", "2022-12-02 10:15:00"],
        "Date": ["2022-10-01", "2022-10-01", "2022-12-02", "2022-12-02", "2022-12-02", "2022-12-02", "2022-12-02", "2022-12-02"],
        "Values": [2, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 3],
    }
)
qa = dataset.lazy().with_columns(pl.col("Timestamps").str.strptime(pl.Datetime, "%Y-%m-%d %T"), pl.col("Date").str.strptime(pl.Date, "%Y-%m-%d"))
df1 = qa.collect()


shape: (8, 3)
┌─────────────────────┬────────────┬────────┐
│ Timestamps          ┆ Date       ┆ Values │
│ ---                 ┆ ---        ┆ ---    │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ date       ┆ i64    │
╞═════════════════════╪════════════╪════════╡
│ 2022-10-01 06:00:00 ┆ 2022-10-01 ┆ 2      │
│ 2022-10-01 08:30:00 ┆ 2022-10-01 ┆ 2      │
│ 2022-12-02 09:00:00 ┆ 2022-12-02 ┆ 1      │
│ 2022-12-02 09:15:00 ┆ 2022-12-02 ┆ 4      │
│ 2022-12-02 09:30:00 ┆ 2022-12-02 ┆ 3      │
│ 2022-12-02 09:45:00 ┆ 2022-12-02 ┆ 2      │
│ 2022-12-02 10:00:00 ┆ 2022-12-02 ┆ 1      │
│ 2022-12-02 10:15:00 ┆ 2022-12-02 ┆ 3      │
└─────────────────────┴────────────┴────────┘
```

In this case we see that on 10-01 there's a tie for Values and on 12-02 the highest Values corresponds to 9:15.

You could try two approaches that start the same...

```
(
    df1
        .groupby('Date')
        .agg(pl.col('Values').max())
        .join(df1, on=['Date','Values'])
        .sort('Timestamps')
        .unique(subset=['Date','Values'])
        .sort("Date", descending=True)
)
```

or

```
(
    df1
        .groupby('Date')
        .agg(pl.col('Values').max())
        .join(df1, on=['Date','Values'])
        .groupby(['Date','Values'])
        .agg(pl.col('Timestamps').min())
        .sort("Date", descending=True)

)
```

I'm not which is more efficient between the sort/unique or the second groupby/agg but in either case you'd get:

```
shape: (2, 3)
┌────────────┬────────┬─────────────────────┐
│ Date       ┆ Values ┆ Timestamps          │
│ ---        ┆ ---    ┆ ---                 │
│ date       ┆ i64    ┆ datetime[μs]        │
╞════════════╪════════╪═════════════════════╡
│ 2022-10-01 ┆ 2      ┆ 2022-10-01 06:00:00 │
│ 2022-12-02 ┆ 4      ┆ 2022-12-02 09:15:00 │
└────────────┴────────┴─────────────────────┘
```

Comment: That looks good, but I still need the timestamp to be corresponding to the max/min value. I added `2022-10-01 04:00:00` to my example to make it clearer. So the max value for `2022-10-01` should be _2_ and the timestamp should be the first one (2022-10-01 06:00:00) that matches the value _2_ . I hope that makes more sense...

Answer (score 1):

You can filter with window expressions

```
res = (
    # select rows with max 'Values' by Date group
    df1.filter(
        pl.col("Values") == pl.max("Values").over("Date")
    # select only the earliest timestamp of each Date group
    ).filter(
        pl.col("Timestamps") == pl.min("Timestamps").over("Date")
    )
)
```

Output:

```
>>> res

shape: (2, 3)
┌─────────────────────┬────────────┬────────┐
│ Timestamps          ┆ Date       ┆ Values │
│ ---                 ┆ ---        ┆ ---    │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ date       ┆ i64    │
╞═════════════════════╪════════════╪════════╡
│ 2022-10-01 06:00:00 ┆ 2022-10-01 ┆ 2      │
│ 2022-12-02 09:15:00 ┆ 2022-12-02 ┆ 4      │
└─────────────────────┴────────────┴────────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting "corresponding" values by row on another column is best done with `join`s. I'm not sure this is the most efficient as I had to do a `unique` and `rename` at the end here, but for now:

```
first_dt = df.select("Values", pl.col("Timestamps").first().over("Values"))

df.groupby("Date")
    .agg(pl.max("Values").alias("max_value"), pl.min("Values").alias("min_value"))
    .join(
        first_dt,
        left_on="max_value",
        right_on="Values",
    )
    .join(first_dt, left_on="min_value", right_on="Values", suffix="_corr_min")
    .unique()
    .rename({"Timestamps": "Timestamps_corr_max"})
```

```
┌────────────┬───────────┬───────────┬─────────────────────┬─────────────────────┐
│ Date       ┆ max_value ┆ min_value ┆ Timestamps_corr_max ┆ Timestamps_corr_min │
│ ---        ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---                 ┆ ---                 │
│ date       ┆ i64       ┆ i64       ┆ datetime[μs]        ┆ datetime[μs]        │
╞════════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═════════════════════╪═════════════════════╡
│ 2022-12-02 ┆ 5         ┆ 4         ┆ 2022-12-02 09:00:00 ┆ 2022-12-02 09:15:00 │
│ 2022-10-01 ┆ 2         ┆ 1         ┆ 2022-10-01 06:00:00 ┆ 2022-10-01 04:00:00 │
└────────────┴───────────┴───────────┴─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┘
```

Comment: I will also use your example if I need more data points in a result. Thank you very much.